# How do I make Cycle 2 overlay text non-transparent?

Tags: css, jquery-cycle2

I am using Cycle 2 [here](http://dev.davids.emarketsouth.com/) with the overlay feature. The opacity control for the background is working correctly but I need the text to be solid white. I have tried the following to modify it but can't get it to respond properly.

Here is the Cycle code:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" 
data-cycle-fx=fade
data-cycle-timeout=5000
data-cycle-pager=".cycle-pager"
>
<!-- empty element for overlay -->
<div class="cycle-overlay"></div>

<img src="images/slider-1.jpg" 
data-cycle-title="From Your Door to our Store!" 
data-cycle-desc="Learn about our route services...">
<img src="images/slider-2.jpg" 
data-cycle-title="From Your Door to our Store!" 
data-cycle-desc="Learn about our route services...">
</div><!-- /.cycle-slideshow -->
<div class="cycle-pager"></div>
```

Here is the CSS I tried:

```
.cycle-overlay div {
    font: small-caps 400 32px "futura-pt",sans-serif;
    color: #fff; 
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1000; 
}
```

I would appreciate any guidance in resolving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use opacity in that case. Use background-color with rgba. 
Here's the code you should be writing:

```
.cycle-overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

And remove opactiy. If you want it 100% black, you can use hex code. If you want a semi transparent background, use rgba instead. The last "a" means alpha value. So, it's just works like opacity.

Comment: Hi Morven, my apologies. I meant to indicate that I am using Cycle 2 (not Fancybox), which changes the nature of the question and the solution.

Comment: The solution is still the same. If you want a semi transparent background with solid text, you should be using `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);` and not `opacity`. Apply that style to the right `div` and remove `opacity`

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.